# How can I add button function into fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, android-videoview

I'm trying to create a learning application the activity will show 3 tabs, my question is how can I put a Video View into the tab. The codes for the button that I know doesn't work. any idea about what syntax should I use when it comes to fragments?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxHDV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
Public class  Tab2Vid extand Fragment implement View.OnClickListener {

    Public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container
                            ,Bundle savedlnstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2video, container, false); 

    Button play = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnplay);

    return rootView; 

    }

    Public void onClick(View view)( 
    switch (view.getId())
        {

            case R.id.btnplay:
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Btn Play clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    } 
}
```